# Postgresql : createdb prompt for password for user with no password

Tags: database, postgresql

I have create a new user in pgsql with no password. But when i try to create a database for this user it prompts for a password

```
>createuser -d -S -R -U postgres test1
Password:
>createdb -U test1 db1
Password:
```

i have tried the superuser password but it gives me the error :

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "test1"
```

Please help,
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative way to create user by prompting password.
You can give -P option while creating user.
Like:

> createuser -d -S -R -U postgres test1

Comment: Could you please edit your answer ? Your example does not show the actual `-P` option...

Comment: The `-P` option is actually a shortcut for `--pwprompt`, which is the opposite of what OP wants, it asks for the password using a prompt. From the documentation[1]: "If given, createuser will issue a prompt for the password of the new user. This is not necessary if you do not plan on using password authentication."

[1] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-createuser.html

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you,

```
psql -c "CREATE DATABASE mydb" "user=postgres dbname=postgres password=something_secret"
```

You need to run this from command-prompt. Go to the PostgreSQL folder where you can find the program `psql` and try this command. `mydb` would be the database name.

Reference: [How to prevent asking for password when creating new database in PostgreSQL 10?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209147/how-to-prevent-asking-for-password-when-creating-new-database-in-postgresql-10)

Thanks to: [Jasen](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/67180/jasen) and [Mladen Uzelac](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/51803/mladen-uzelac)

Comment: The point is to prevent the command from being stored in the terminal history. This fails that